# How to make aninterface not too specific

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I am creating a class that is supposed to upload files to many a S3 Bucket with a presignedUrl.
For now, I just have to upload files to a S3 Bucket.
But in the future, i will have to upload files in others systems.

```
public interface uploader {

    public void upload(String presignedUrl, InputStream inputStream) throws Exception;
}
```

My concern is the first parameter `String presignedUrl` and this : `throws Exception`
I think it is too specific and i dont think my futur implementations will fit this interface.

How can i design my interface to be less specific ?

I simplified like this :

```
public interface uploader {

    public void upload(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception;
}
```

But now, i dont know how to get my `presigendUrl`

Comment: `Exception` is generic enough so seems to be ok. For upload ask yourself how many types of uploads you know or want to support and define a wrapper objects for those. Somethng like `UploadTarget` , `HTTPUploadTarget` and so on then use that wrapper on the interface

Answer (score 1):

Your interface is not too specific. It has only single method (aka functional interface) - by definition smallest and most composable abstraction. You will easily create new implementation in future.

But `throws Exception` is too generic. There are 3 ways to change it:

1. Consider replace it with `RuntimeException` instead of just generic checked `Exception`.
2. Use custom exception like `UploadException` extended from RuntimeException.
3. Or remove exception from interface contract at all.

Couple more tips:

1. Start interface name with capital letter (like `Uploader`, not `uploader`). It is Java convention.
2. Use wrapper class for `upload` method arguments insead of `String presignedUrl, InputStream inputStream`.

Comment: How would you construct this wrapper class ? I feel that i just move the problem ...

Comment: Crete new abstract class UploadRequest. Set required data properties inside (String presignedUrl, InputStream inputStream). Create child class inherited from UploadRequest (let's call it S3UploadRequest). Then change signature of upload method in Uploader interface to "public void upload(UploadRequest request)". Now you have abstracted arguments in UploadRequest wrapper class. 
Actually this is not so important. Just create working project. Do not try to build everything perfectly from the beginning. It's ok to do it iteratively.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... But now, i dont know how to get my `presigendUrl`"*

That would be left to the implementation.

```java
class S3Upload implements uploader {
    String presignedUrl;
    
    @Override
    public void upload(InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

> *"... How can i design my interface to be less specific ? ..."*

```java
interface uploader {

    void upload() throws Exception;
}
```

Here is the *Java* tutorial on *interface*s.
*[Interfaces (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Interfaces and Inheritance)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html)*.